# Java: JTable adding and moving columns

Tags: java, jtable

im quite new in Java.
I want to add Columns in a JTable at a specified index. 
For this i am using addColumn(..) and then move them with moveColumn(...), this works great at the first time, but when i add another column it kind of moves also the other(before added columns).

Do you have any suggestions?

this is the code i've written in the TableModel is:

```
    public void addColumn(Object columnName, 
                      Vector columnData, JTable table) {

    int moveTo = ((Integer)columnName);
    boolean unselected = moveTo==-1;
    super.addColumn(this.getColumnCount(), columnData);
    if(!unselected) {//if a column was selected 
        table.moveColumn(this.getColumnCount()-1, moveTo+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> this works great at the first time,
>   but when i add another column it kind
>   of moves also the other(before added
>   columns).

I don't understand what that means.

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.